# Google Cloud Anchors for iOS - Error in authentication

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, arcore, google-developers-console

I'm not able to implement token authentication with google cloud anchors on iOS:

I follow those steps:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/ios/cloud-anchors/developer-guide#token-authentication

but when I try to host an anchor I obtain always the error GARCloudAnchorStateErrorNotAuthorized.

I think that the jwt is valid, I tried with the one obtained via oauth2l command and even with one generated via a node.js app.

the flow with the ApiKey works correctly, but when I remove the apikey from initialization and pass the token the problems began.

anyone has any ideas?

the code is:

```
class TestViewController: ARViewController {
    
    let garSession = try! GARSession.session()
    
    var oldStatus: GARFeatureMapQuality = .insufficient
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        garSession.delegate = self
        garSession.delegateQueue = .main
        garSession.setAuthToken(token)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: arView) else {
            print("no location")
            return
        }
        guard let result = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first else {
            print("no result")
            return
        }
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: result.worldTransform)
        try! garSession.hostCloudAnchor(anchor, ttlDays: 20)
    }
    
    override func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        super.session(session, didUpdate: frame)
        if case .normal = frame.camera.trackingState {
            try! garSession.update(frame)
            let status = try! garSession.estimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting(frame.camera.transform)
            if oldStatus != status {
                switch status {
                case .good:
                    print("STATUS: GOOD")
                case .insufficient:
                    print("STATUS: INSUFFICIENT")
                case .sufficient:
                    print("STATUS: SUFFICIENT")
                }
            }
            oldStatus = status
        }
    }
}

extension TestViewController: GARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: GARSession, didFailToHost anchor: GARAnchor) {
        checkStatus(anchor)
    }
    
    func session(_ session: GARSession, didHost anchor: GARAnchor) {
        print("FINALLY!")
    }
    
    private func checkStatus(_ anchor: GARAnchor) {
        switch anchor.cloudState {
        case .errorCloudIdNotFound:
            print("[GARSession] cannot find anchor with identifier: \(anchor.identifier)")
        case .errorHostingDatasetProcessingFailed:
            print("errorHostingDatasetProcessingFailed")
        case .errorHostingServiceUnavailable:
            print("errorHostingServiceUnavailable")
        case .errorInternal:
            print("errorInternal")
        case .errorNotAuthorized:
            print("[GARSession] cannot operate on anchor with identifier: \(anchor.identifier), error: NotAuthorized")
        case .errorResolvingSdkVersionTooNew:
            print("errorResolvingSdkVersionTooNew")
        case .errorResolvingSdkVersionTooOld:
            print("errorResolvingSdkVersionTooOld")
        case .errorResourceExhausted:
            print("errorResourceExhausted")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```